# How to create a table spanning the whole page with equal sized boxes and is the length and width of the page?

Tags: tables

Thank you for all of the help in advance. I am trying to create the following in overleaf. This one is done in word. I am honestly not sure how to go about it. I have done a few things like start a table that spans the width of the page but not sure how to make it span the the height of the page. Also, what to do if I want the table in the middle of the page and I still want the spacing to be equal.
[image]

```
\begin{tblr}{|X[1,l]|X[1,l]|X[3,l]|X[l]|}
\hline
\hline
 Symbol & Name & Definition & Example \\
 \hline
 \hline
 $\mathbb{N}$ & & & \\
 \hline
 $\mathbb{Z}$ & & & \\
 \hline
 $\mathbb{Q}$ & & & \\
  \hline
 $\mathbb{R}$ & & & \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}
```

Comment: So, the size of the boxes should be such that if the table starts at a certain position on the page (there might be one or more lines of text above), it has four rows of equal height and the table fills the rest of the page?

Comment: Hi, yes please! That sounds right. The width is the width of the page and the height just spans the remaining part of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the remaining space on the page which is not totally straight-forward. An approach using Ti*k*Z matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\newlength{\matrixcolumnwidth}
\newlength{\matrixrowheight}
\newlength{\matrixheight}
\NewDocumentCommand{\matrixfill}{ m m O{} +m }{%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (matrix start) at (0,0); }%
    \vfill\null%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (matrix end) at (0,0); }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, inner sep=5pt]
        \pgfmathsetlength{\matrixcolumnwidth}{
            \linewidth/#1 - 2 * \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep} - \pgflinewidth)
        }
        \pgfextracty{\matrixheight}{\pgfpointdiff
            {\pgfpointanchor{matrix end}{center}}
            {\pgfpointanchor{matrix start}{center}}}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\matrixrowheight}{
            \matrixheight/#2 - 2 * \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep} - \pgflinewidth)
        }
        \node[
            anchor=north west, 
            matrix, 
            matrix of nodes, 
            nodes in empty cells, 
            inner sep=0pt,
            ampersand replacement=\&, 
            nodes={
                draw, 
                anchor=center, 
                inner sep=5pt,
                text width={\matrixcolumnwidth}, 
                text depth={\matrixrowheight-0.66em}, 
                text height={0.66em}
            },
            #3] at (matrix start) { #4 };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

Hello

\noindent\matrixfill{2}{3}{ 
    a) \& b) \\ 
     \& \\ 
     \& \\ 
}

\newpage

Hello

\bigskip

Bye

\noindent\matrixfill{2}{3}{ 
    a) \& b) \\ 
     \& \\ 
     \& \\ 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @user292225 It is not exactly a table ... but depending on what you want to do, it might be sufficient.